# I always wonder about 'to let'. The origin, the meaning, the concept

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, let

[OxfordDictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/let) has an entry for this -

> to let - *(Of a room or property) available for rent*

But then how is that? Is it a verb phrase? How does it mean *"available for rent?"* Is it something to do with *to **let anyone come** in the house?* :)

Comment: OED's relevant definition (verb 1, sense 8a) is *To grant the temporary possession and use of (land, buildings, rooms, movable property) to another in consideration of rent or hire. †Formerly also, to lend (money) at interest.* The first citation was over 1000 years ago, when English was *very* different to today, so I don't think it's very meaningful to analyse the usage in terms of *current* meanings. The now-obsolete sense of ***let** = To allow to remain; to leave behind; to abstain from taking away, using, consuming, occupying, etc.* is more closely related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "available for rent" because "let" is a synonym for lease/rent, as FumbleFingers explains above. It's chiefly BrE (or at least not AmE) - see:

- [Should I let out my current flat when I buy another one?](http://www.theguardian.com/money/2013/aug/28/let-flat-buy-another)
- [Association of Residential Letting Agents](http://www.arla.co.uk/)

The "available" part is just understood - possibly because historically this phrasing is used in small newspaper ads and on signs, where shorter is better.

Answer (score -2):

"to let"  in this use has the meaning "to let someone  have something".
Other languages use clear compound verbs for this use. When written on a house, English uses the simplex verb as a misunderstanding is not possible.
It can only mean: We let you have the use of this house if you pay a rent.

Comment: I'm that sense, I can use to let for anything I want to give off on rent. Say car. Isn't it?